# Can I use a T410 hard drive in a W510 laptop without formatting anything?

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad

My T410 laptop LCD is broken. I have a spare W510 laptop.

Can I use the existing T410 hard drive in the W510 without formatting it?

If so, what are the risks involved with doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risks are

1. It will not boot into windows and will freeze at some point in the boot process.
2. It will bluescreen when loading hardware drivers
3. It could corrupt the Windows installation to the point it will need a repair to work in the old system again.
4. If windows loads it will more than likely kill the Windows activation for that OS installation due to a different motherboard, it will have to be re-activated by calling Microsoft's activation phone number.
5. No real damage to either notebook will occur.